# show in_reply_to_status_id while using api.get_status /Python

Tags: python, tweepy

What Can I do if I want to show in_reply_to_status_id, in_reply_to_user_id and in_reply_to_screen_name in  api.get_status?
My code is as follows, can anyone help me please?

```
tweets_df4 = pd.DataFrame()
for tweet in tqdm(replies3):
    hashtags = []
    try:
        for hashtag in tweet.entities["hashtags"]:
            hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])
        text = api.get_status(id=tweet.id, tweet_mode='extended').full_text
    except:
        pass
    tweets_df4 = tweets_df4.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_name': "@" +tweet.user.screen_name,
                                               'user_id' : tweet.user.id,
                                               'screen_name' : tweet.user.name,
                                               'user_location': tweet.user.location,
                                               'user_description': tweet.user.description,
                                               'user_created': tweet.user.created_at,
                                               'user_followers': tweet.user.followers_count,
                                               'user_friends': tweet.user.friends_count,
                                               'user_favourites': tweet.user.favourites_count,
                                               'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                                               'date': tweet.created_at,
                                               'text': text, 
                                               'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
                                               'source': tweet.source,
                                               'is_retweet': tweet.retweeted,
                                               "tweet_id" : tweet.id_str,
                                               "reply" :tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str,
                                                 }, index=[0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
for tweet in tqdm(replies3):
    print(tweet.in_reply_to_user_id)
    print(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id)
    print(tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name)
```

from the api call, does this work?

```
api.get_status(id=tweet.id, tweet_mode='extended').in_reply_to_user_id
```